# How to define same css property for multiple classes generated dynamically using ngFor (Angular)?

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to write css for dynamic classes, for that I generated classes using ngFor like below

```
<div style="max-height: 450px;" *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index" class="card{{i + 1 }}">
.....
</div>
```

Now I am writing css for above dynamic classes like this ->

```
@media (min-width: 1399px) {
  .card2,
  .card6 {
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .card3,
  .card7 {
   padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card2,
  .card4,
  .card6 {
   padding-left: 0px;
 }
}
```

Now I have less than 8 divs but it can be above 20 and then I will be in trouble.

So Is there any shortest way for defining above css rules like card(n+1){....} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sass or less, you can use control directives, your sass code would look like :

```
@for $i from 0 through 20 {
  .card-#{$i} { padding-left: 0px; }
}
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58133161)

Comment: Thanks you @ibenjelloun !!! Here you give static value 20...instead of that can we give here dynamic value such as length of list etc.....

Comment: The control directives are executed before runtime, on runtime only css code produced by sass will be executed. I don't think that it is possible to give the length of a javascript array to a sass control directive as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Use your current classes as IDs, and use a common class for all.

```
class="card" id="card-{{ i }}"
```

Comment: If you need special styles for given cards, please explain the end goal and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can see my implementation for inserting classes dynamically [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eladmt).

Basically you need to create a function that returns your class's name.

If what you need is to create specific CSS styles for every n+1 card element then you can try this:

```
card:nth-child(n+1){
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no pattern and therefore you cannot use sass, then you could look at `[ngStyle]` directive. Example of using:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index" class="card-{{i + 1 }}" [ngStyle]="calcStyle(item, i)">
.....
</div>
```

and return your expected style in your .ts file, like:

```
calcStyle(item, i){
  if (i==6){
     return {
       'padding-left': '0px;',
       'padding-right': '0px;'
       }
    }
 }
```

But i think, that you should try to avoid setting padding by index of current item. Instead try to use some grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy. Just change the value type of your class attribute to accept javascript instead string and add the concatenation.

```
<div
  style="max-height: 450px;"
  *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index"
  [class]="'card' + (i + 1)">
  .....
</div>
```